# Как мониторить ВМ в hyper-v 2008 r2?

Tags: windows, powershell, zabbix, wmi, hyper-v

Хотел мониторить через скрипт на powershell модуль get-vm, но проблема, что этот модуль не подходит для 2008 R2 (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/hh846767(v=ws.11))
Как быть??
Есть ли альтернативы?

Скрипт(https://github.com/ameiji/Zabbix-HyperV-Templates)

Comment: Какая у вас версия powershell?

Comment: что значит не подходит? дополните вопрос подробностями

Comment: PS точно как администратор запускаете?

Comment: Какая у вас версия powershell? – Viktor Tomilov
была 2, поставил 3 версию.

Comment: Да я запускаю от имени Администратора.
Я на сайте microsoft написано что модуль get-vm поддерживается только в windows server 2012.
может я что-то путаю!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Полноценная поддержка WMI для Hyper-V появилась лишь, начиная с Server-2012. У меня нет сейчас 2008 R2, поэтому проверить не могу, но, насколько я помню, с обновлением до версии 3 в Powershell появлялась возможность мониторить Hyper-V, правда, были заморочки с правами (для чего и нужен запуск под админом).

Если же никак, можно пойти другим путём: поставить [PowerShell Management Library for Hyper-V](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=pshyperv). Ставится просто, работается с ней тоже просто. Вот список самых полезных функций:

```
Подключение к виртуальной машине
New-VMConnectSession

Манипулирование состоянием виртуальных машин
Get-VMState, Set-VMState, Convert-VmState,
Ping-VM, Test-VMHeartBeat, Shutdown-VM, Start-VM, Stop-VM, Suspend-VM
Get-VMKVP, Add-KVP, Remove-KVP, Get-VMJPEG

Возможность делать бэкапы, экспорт виртуальных машин и снятие снэпшотов
Export-VM, Import-VM, Get-VMSnapshot, Choose-VMSnapshot, Apply-VMSnapshot, New-VMSnapshot ,Remove-VMSnapshot, Rename-VMSnapShot, Update-VMSnapshot, Get-VMSnapshotTree, Get-VmBackupScript

Добавление и удаление вирт. машин, настройка их свойств
New-VM, Remove-VM, Set-VM, Get-VMCPUCount, Set-VMCPUCount, Get-VMMemory, Set-VMMemory, Set-VMSerialPort

Управление дисковыми контроллерами
Get-VMDiskController
Add-VMSCSIController, Remove-VMSCSIcontroller
Get-VMDriveByController, Add-VMDRIVE, Remove-VMdrive
Get-VMDiskByDrive, Add-VMDISK, Set-VMDisk, Get-VMDisk
Get-VMFloppyDisk, Add-VMFloppyDisk
Add-VMNewHardDisk

Управление сетевыми интерфейсами
Get-VMNic, List-VMNic, Choose-VMNIC, Add-VMNIC, Remove-VMNIC, Set-VMNICAddress, Set-VMNICConnection, Get-VMNicport,
Get-VMnicSwitch, Choose-VMSwitch, New-VMSwitchPort, Get-VMByMACaddress, Choose-VMExternalEthernet,
New-VMExternalSwitch, New-VMInternalSwitch,New-VmPrivateSwitch

Работа с VHD файлами
Get-VHDDefaultPath, Get-VHDInfo, New-VHD, Compact-VHD, Test-VHD,Convert-VHD,Merge-VHD,Mount-VHD, Unmount-VHD
```

Comment: Для Server-2012 имеет смысл ставить эту библиотеку или можно обойтись системными классами?

Comment: @AlexeyKozlov на ваше усмотрение. Она была немного расширена по сравнению со стандартной, но MS могли что-то уже поменять, я достаточно давно не модерировал Hyper-V.